# post select results to another sql table

Tags: php, sql

I am having trouble posting the results of a select function to an sql table

I have a select function which pulls data from an sql table (see code below),

```
label for="test">Test:</label><br>
    <select id="test" name="test">
<?php
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM test WHERE selected is null");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){
    echo '<option value="'. $row['value'] .'">'. $row['date'] .'</option>';
    }?>
    </select>
```

When the form has been submitted, it loads another page called sumbit.php which includes the code below

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$test = $_POST['test'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO submit (name,phone,email,test,comments) 
VALUES 
('$name','$phone','$email','$test','$comment')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

My problem is that the test field doesnt update (the rest of the fields are text fields and do update in the submit table), please can someone advise what is wrong with my code or advise of a better way of posting the results of the select box into the sql table?

Comment: This might not help your current issue, but you'll probably want to look into using _prepared statements_ and _placeholders_ for your INSERT query. There are some links on how to do this on the [PHP tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), under the "**How do I make my database queries secure from SQL injection?**" section.

Comment: Give Your db schema for test field. Also check for any mysql error

Answer (score 0):

first a few words of advice, you absolutely need to learn about PDO and prepared statements, read [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) to learn how to do things properly.

you need to include a `value` field on your SQL statement, without it `$row['value']` will always evaluate to `null` this causes that your `option` tags to have no value, leading to `$_POST['test']` to be always empty.